# How do I add a picture to the middle of a radial chart in Highchart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

I attempted to add a picture to the middle of the chart, but it appears on the upper left side instead. Is it feasible to include that or not?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  colors: ["#92D050", "#97BE49", "#00B0F0", "#FFC000", "#FF0000"],
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true,
    polar: true
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Test'
  },
  tooltip: {
    outside: true
  },
  pane: {
    size: '85%',
    innerSize: '20%',
    endAngle: 270
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      useHTML: true,
      allowOverlap: true,
      step: 1,
      y: 3,
      style: {
        fontSize: '13px'
      }
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    categories: [
      "M3", "M2", "M1", "M0", "Treshold"
    ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#333'
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickInterval: 0,
    reversedStacks: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    labels: {
       enabled: false
   },
    showLastLabel: true,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      borderWidth: 0,
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0.15
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Gold medals',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [148, 113, 104, 71, 77]
  }]
}, function(chart) {
    var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.series[0].center);
var textY = chart.plotTop + (chart.series[0].center);
    /*     chart.renderer.circle(textX, textY, 10).attr({
            fill: '#ddd',
        }).add(); */

    chart.renderer.image(
        'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png',
        textX - 15,
        textY - 15,
        30,
        30
    ).add();
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 600px;
}

.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}

.ld-label {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ld-url-input {
  width: 500px;
}

.ld-time-input {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<!-- Flag sprites service provided by Martijn Lafeber,
  https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/blob/master/LICENSE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/downloads/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/flags16.css">

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with  `transform` in CSS.  I added this to your CSS:

```
image {
  transform: translate(48%, 48%);
  }
```

Here are the results:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  colors: ["#92D050", "#97BE49", "#00B0F0", "#FFC000", "#FF0000"],
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true,
    polar: true
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Test'
  },
  tooltip: {
    outside: true
  },
  pane: {
    size: '85%',
    innerSize: '20%',
    endAngle: 270
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      useHTML: true,
      allowOverlap: true,
      step: 1,
      y: 3,
      style: {
        fontSize: '13px'
      }
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    categories: [
      "M3", "M2", "M1", "M0", "Treshold"
    ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#333'
    },
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickInterval: 0,
    reversedStacks: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    labels: {
       enabled: false
   },
    showLastLabel: true,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      borderWidth: 0,
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0.15
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Gold medals',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [148, 113, 104, 71, 77]
  }]
}, function(chart) {
    var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.series[0].center);
var textY = chart.plotTop + (chart.series[0].center);
    /*     chart.renderer.circle(textX, textY, 10).attr({
            fill: '#ddd',
        }).add(); */

    chart.renderer.image(
        'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png',
        textX - 15,
        textY - 15,
        30,
        30
    ).add();
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 600px;
}

.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
  background: #f1f7ff;
}

.ld-label {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ld-url-input {
  width: 500px;
}

.ld-time-input {
  width: 40px;
}

image {
  transform: translate(48%, 48%);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<!-- Flag sprites service provided by Martijn Lafeber,
  https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/blob/master/LICENSE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/downloads/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/flags16.css">

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
  <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration:

```
 function(chart) {
    let edge = 30,
  x = chart.xAxis[0].center[0] + chart.plotLeft - edge/2,
  y = chart.yAxis[0].center[1] + chart.plotTop - edge/2;

  chart.renderer.image(
    'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png',
    x,
    y,
    edge,
    edge
  ).add();
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/um5ov94r/